# Codeigniter Escaping Periods in Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this bit that I'm using to search IP addresses in a database.

```
$this->db->where("IP1='$ip' OR IP2='$ip'");
```

When I use it, it is escaping the periods in the IP addresses and breaking the query by producing this.

```
SELECT * FROM (`xxxx`) WHERE `IP1='111`.`111`.`111`.`111'`
```

I want it to produce:

```
SELECT * FROM (`xxxx`) WHERE IP1='111.111.111.111' OR IP2 = '111.111.111.111'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select):

"`$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with back-ticks."

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

You better make sure that you are sanatizing your variables if you do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the `where` helper.  According to [the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), you can include an optional third parameter of `FALSE` to stop CodeIgniter from escaping your table/field names:

```
$this->db->where("IP1='$ip' OR IP2='$ip'", NULL, FALSE);
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this
```

However, if `$ip` comes from user input you will no longer be protected from SQL injection in this query.